# Ohio DNR Oil Gas Lat / Long Conversion in ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-10.1, excel, latitude-longitude, united-states, oil-gas

Is anyone familiar with the Ohio Oil Well Search off their website?  For the Lat/Long, they have WH_X and WH_Y.  The numbers in their do not match up with the actual Lats/Longs off the OHio Well Viewer.  This is how it looks.   This is in Belmont County, OHIO (Warren Township)

WH_X    WH_Y
2361000 719070
2359833 714452

Is there a Conversion to the Lats/Longs within ArcGIS 10.1?  Or is there another method within Excel?

Answer (score 1):

As the [Well Record Definitions](http://oilandgas.ohiodnr.gov/well-information/well-search-definitions) list implies, if the values aren't in lat/lon, they're using NAD27 State Plane (which uses the US survey foot). Belmont county is in the South zone. The list doesn't match up exactly to "WH".

Creating features from this data is harder because it's polygon (extent) rather than point. There used to be a sample in the geoprocessing toolbox, 'Create Feature from Text' but it's deprecated (but still installed). If you want to map it as points, use Add XY Data in ArcMap.

Comment: I ended up deleting the map and starting new.  There was a glitch as I had it NAD27 and it worked fine with how the XY was set up.